# RREF of matrix and corresponding row space

Tags: linear-algebra

I recently did an exercise where I was asked to find the reduced row echelon form of a matrix so that I would then be able to find the row and column rank, etc. When attempting the reduced row echelon form for the first time, I noticed that early on in elimination, I obtained a zero row.

$$A = \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 2 \\
    1 & 2 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 6 \\
    1 & 2 & 4 & 6 & 8 \\
    \end{pmatrix}$$

Row operations: $$-R1+R2, R3+R4 \rightarrow R3, \\-5R2+R3, -3R2+R4, \\-R2+R1, -R3+R1, \\-R3+R2, -R3+R4.$$

$$\text{RREF}(A) = \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 2 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    \end{pmatrix}$$

$$\text{Basis row}A=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 2 \\
1 & 2 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 6 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

For some reason, I didn't want to permute the matrix, so I started from scratch and added the fourth row to the third row so that I wouldn't need to do any permutations. While I ended up getting the correct $\text{RREF}$ of the matrix, because of my method, I ended up eliminating the wrong row (row $4$ instead of row $3$) and got the wrong row space as a result.

While I am certain that my row operations were correct, I am confused why my method failed in letting me get the correct basis vectors for the row space, as I was utilizing the definition that all nonzero rows are row vectors. I really appreciate any and all help!

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please use the [mathjax basic tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and enhance your question

Comment: People, please stop dropping -1's on new users' posts if it's just formatting.  Anyone who gets satisfaction out of such a thing, much less think it's productive, is just a pathetic person.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Careful, it's the nonzero rows of $\text{RREF}(A)$ that can be used as a basis for the row space of $A$, **not** the corresponding rows of $A$.  Consider for example $A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 2 & 2 \\ 1 & 2 \end{pmatrix} \to \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} $ where the row space is all of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and one possible basis is $\bigl\{ (1,0) , (0,1) \bigr\}$ and another one is $\bigl\{ (1,1) , (1,2) \bigr\}$ (that is, rows 1 and 3 of $A$), but rows 1 and 2 are multiples hence linearly dependent hence not a basis.

More generally, row reduction preserves the span of the rows but does **not** preserve (absence of) relations between the rows.  For columns, it's the other way around.